# Sobreposição dos elementos com padding

Tags: css3

Quando utilizo a propriedade `padding`, não gera o espaçamento correto nos quatro lados dos elementos. Ao utilizar o **inspessor de elementos** do Firefox observo que há uma sobreposição do efeito do `padding`.

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
    <div class="quadrante-principal-conteudo-sub">
   <span>Vitória</span><span>Vila Velha</span><span>Guarapari</span>  <span>Anchieta</span>
   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.quadrante-principal-conteudo-sub{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 595px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.quadrante-principal-conteudo-sub span{
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão, o elemento `span` possui a propriedade `display` com o valor `inline`. Propriedades como `padding` e `margin` não funcionam em elementos `inline`.

Para resolver o problema, mude o valor da propriedade  `display` para `inline-block`:

```
div.quadrante-principal-conteudo-sub span{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    overflow: auto; 
}
```